# overload virtual function with different parameters in c++

Tags: c++

I want to overload virtual function with different parameters in c++ but it doesn't work.

```
virtual void Draw( int nDeltaX, int nDeltaY);
virtual void Draw( int nDeltaX, int nDeltaY, bool m_bFlag);
```

Can you tell me the reason?

Comment: Elaborate your question some more, please. How does it not work?

Comment: If you use different parameters, then you don't override, but overload the functions. As for your problem, can you please show us what you have tried? Preferably by creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. Also include more details, like errors you get, expected and actual behavior, etc.

Comment: I have a function in class Base{virtual void Draw( int nDeltaX, int nDeltaY);} I want to overload function Draw in class Derived{virtual void Draw( int nDeltaX, int nDeltaY, bool m_bFlag);} with one more parameter  bool m_bFlag.

Comment: Clarify your question, please, by including an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I believe I know a solution to your problem, but I cannot be sure until it's clear what your problem really is.

Comment: @MiroslavAvramov: You can over*load* the function just as you describe, and call it via the derived class. But it won't over*ride* the base-class function, since an override must match the signature in order to be called via the base class without knowing what the derived class is. Could you describe exactly what you're trying to achieve, and what exactly goes wrong?

Comment: I want to use this flag in class Derived to start and stop drawing picture.

Comment: virtual void Draw( int nDeltaX, int nDeltaY) = 0;

Answer (score 6):

The answer is - because that's the way C++ works. The parameters must be the same. C++11 standard says in 10.3.2:

> If a virtual member function vf is declared in a class Base and in a class Derived, derived directly or indirectly from Base, a member function vf with the same name, parameter-type-list (8.3.5), cv-qualification, and refqualifier (or absence of same) as Base::vf is declared, then Derived::vf is also virtual (whether or not it is so declared) and it overrides 11 1 Base::vf.