# Override virtual function with more parameters

Tags: c++, interface, overloading, virtual

I have an array of happy people.
Each happy person has a virtual function called updateHappiness() which is used to update their happiness attribute.
Each person likes their own thing.

Rain lovers are happy persons who really like hearing the sound of the rain and it increases their happiness level. They inherit from the happy person class.

As a consequence, they need to know when it is raining while updating their happiness by overloading the updateHappiness() function with updateHappiness(bool isRaining) as in this post : [overload virtual function with different parameters in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227189/override-virtual-function-with-different-parameters-in-c), however, this is a problem because there are many kinds of people and we would like to update them all by calling the same function for every person.

We could have the parameter stored inside of the person class and pass it in the class constructor as in this post : [Override number of parameters of pure virtual functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919584/override-number-of-parameters-of-pure-virtual-functions) however rain is not a constant state and we would have to call a function updateRainState(bool isRaining) which would cause the same problem as before.

We could pass the parameter bool isRaining to every person even though they don't care about the rain but it would also be a problem because some people like the rain, some people like seeing the daylight, some people like it when their friends are happy... so it would add many useless parameters and it seems like a waste.

Finally, the best solution I could think of is to have a static function in the weather class to get the rain state without passing it as a parameter but it would look like a global variable and some people say that it is really bad!

What would you do to solve this problem ?

Here is an example code of what the classes are like :

```
class HappyPerson
{
public:
    HappyPerson(): m_happinness(0) {}
    virtual void updateHappinness() { m_happinness++; }

protected:
    int m_happinness;
};

class Weather
{
public:
    static int isRaining() { return raining; }

private:
    static bool raining;
};

bool Weather::raining(0);

class RainLover : public HappyPerson
{
public:
    RainLover() : HappyPerson() {}
    void updateHappinness() { m_happinness++; if (Weather::isRaining()) m_happinness++; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<HappyPerson*> happyPeople;
    happyPeople.push_back(new RainLover);

    // ... add many other persons

    std::vector<HappyPerson*>::iterator it;
    for (it = happyPeople.begin(); it != happyPeople.end(); it++)
    {
        (*it)->updateHappinness();
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing is for sure, those people aren't happy to be stored as raw pointers in a container. Use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<HappyPerson>>` instead.

Comment: In the context of your application, would it make sense for every 'HappyPerson' to be aware of the Weather?  Persons interested in Weather could register to receive alerts when there is a  change in Weather notify so they could query the aspects of the weather they are interested in...

Comment: It's just an example, they are still happy don't worry. I had to use some pointers for the polymorphism to be effective

Comment: No, every person is not interested in the weather, they could be interested in anything

Comment: @MaxV37: Dan's point is still valid. You should use event callbacks instead. When something changes, only interested people are affected, no need to waste time and effect passing around the change to everyone. If a person's happiness depends on the Weather, then have the person register for Weather change events. If a person's happiness depends on another person's happiness, then have the person register for the other person's happiness change events. And so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider taking a completely different approach - use event callbacks instead.

When something in particular changes, only interested people are affected, so you should not waste time and effect trying to passing around the change to everyone else.

If a person's happiness depends on the Weather, then have the person register for Weather change events.
If a person's happiness depends on another person's happiness, then have the person register for the other person's happiness change events.

And so on.

For example:

```
class HappyPerson;

class HappinessChangeListener
{
public:
    void happinessChanged(HappyPerson *person, bool isHappier) = 0;
};

class HappyPerson
{
public:
    HappyPerson();
    virtual ~HappyPerson() {}

    void updateHappiness(int amount);

    void registerHappinessChangeListener(HappinessChangeListener *listener);
    void unregisterHappinessChangeListener(HappinessChangeListener *listener);
);

protected:
    int m_happinness;
    std::vector<HappinessChangeListener*> happinessChangeListeners;

    void happinessChanged(bool isHappier);
};

...

HappyPerson::HappyPerson()
    : m_happinness(0)
{
}

void HappyPerson::updateHappiness(int amount)
{
    if (amount != 0)
    {
        m_happinness += amount;
        happinessChanged(amount > 0);
    }
}

void HappyPerson::registerHappinessChangeListener(HappinessChangeListener *listener)
{
    happinessChangeListeners.push_back(listener);
}

void HappyPerson::unregisterHappinessChangeListener(HappinessChangeListener *listener)
{
    std::vector<HappinessChangeListener*>::iterator i = std::find(happinessChangeListeners.begin(), happinessChangeListeners.end(), listener);
    if (i != happinessChangeListeners.end())
        happinessChangeListeners.erase(i);
}

void HappyPerson::happinessChanged(bool isHappier)
{
    for(std::vector<HappinessChangeListener*>::iterator i = happinessChangeListeners.begin(); i != happinessChangeListeners.end(); ++i)
        i->happinessChanged(this, isHappier);
}
```

```
class Weather;

class WeatherChangeListener
{
public:
    void weatherChanged(Weather *weather) = 0;
};

class Weather
{
public:
    Weather();

    void rainStarted();
    void rainStopped();
    bool isRaining();

    void registerWeatherChangeListener(WeatherChangeListener *listener);
    void unregisterWeatherChangeListener(WeatherChangeListener *listener);

protected:
    bool m_raining;
    std::vector<WeatherChangeListener*> weatherChangeListeners;

    void weatherChanged();
};

...

Weather::Weather()
    : m_raining(false)
{
}

void Weather::rainStarted()
{
    if (!m_rRaining)
    {
        m_rRaining = true;
        weatherChanged();
    }
}

void Weather::rainStopped()
{
    if (m_rRaining)
    {
        m_rRaining = false;
        weatherChanged();
    }
}

bool Weather::isRaining()
{
    return m_raining;
}

void Weather::registerWeatherChangeListener(WeatherChangeListener *listener)
{
    weatherChangeListeners.push_back(listener);
}

void Weather::unregisterWeatherChangeListener(WeatherChangeListener *listener)
{
    std::vector<WeatherChangeListener*>::iterator i = std::find(weatherChangeListeners.begin(), weatherChangeListeners.end(), listener);
    if (i != weatherChangeListeners.end())
        weatherChangeListeners.erase(i);
}

void Weather::weatherChanged()
{
    for(std::vector<WeatherChangeListener*>::iterator i = weatherChangeListeners.begin(); i != weatherChangeListeners.end(); ++i)
        i->weatherChanged(this);
}
```

```
class RainLover : public HappyPerson, public WeatherChangeListener
{
public:
    RainLover(std::shared_ptr<Weather> &weather);
    ~RainLover();

    void weatherChanged(Weather *weather);

protected:
    std::shared_ptr<Weather> m_weather;
};

...

RainLover::RainLover(std::shared_ptr<Weather> &weather)
    : HappyPerson(), m_weather(weather)
{
    m_weather->registerWeatherChangeListener(this);
}

RainLover::~RainLover()
{
    m_weather->unregisterWeatherChangeListener(this);
}

void RainLover::weatherChanged(Weather *weather)
{
    updateHappiness(weather->isRaining() ? 1 : -1);
}
```

```
class HappyLover : public HappyPerson, public HappinessChangeListener
{
public:
    HappyLover(std::shared_ptr<HappyPerson> &person);
    ~HappyLover();

    void happinessChanged(HappyPerson *person, bool isHappier);

protected:
    std::shared_ptr<HappyPerson> m_person;
};

...

HappyLover::HappyLover(std::shared_ptr<HappyPerson> &person)
    : HappyPerson(), m_person(person)
{
    m_person->registerHappinessChangeListener(this);
}

HappyLover::~HappyLover()
{
    m_person->unregisterHappinessChangeListener(this);
}

void HappyLover::happinessChanged(HappyPerson *person, bool isHappier)
{
    updateHappiness(isHappier ? 1 : -1);
}
```

```
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Weather> weather(new Weather);
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<HappyPerson>> happyPeople;

    happyPeople.push_back(std::shared_ptr<HappyPerson>(new RainLover(weather)));
    // or: happyPeople.push_back(std::make_shared<RainLover>(weather));

    happyPeople.push_back(std::shared_ptr<HappyPerson>(new HappyLover(happyPeople[0])));
    // or: happyPeople.push_back(std::make_shared_ptr<HappyLover>(happyPeople[0]));

    // ... add many other persons

    weather->rainStarted();
    ...
    weather->rainStopped();

    ...
}
```